# Read Binary files on Python

Tags: python, matlab, readfile

I would like to write the equivalence of this matlab code to python when reading binary file

```
fid=fopen('File', 'rb')
fread(fid, 17, 'int8', 'l');
[twf, points] = fread(fid, 'int16', 'l');
twf = fread(fid, 'int16', 'l');
fclose(fid)
```

Thanks

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and [`numpy.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html#numpy.fromfile) look useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect in two places:

1. [`fread`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) returns the number of characters (bytes) read, not the number of data points read. Since you read `'int16'`, `points` is twice the number of data points in your case.
2. The last `fread` is not necessary, since `[twf, points] = fread(fid, 'int16', 'l');` already reads the whole remaining file. Actually you are overwriting your read data with nothing.

Anyway, here is the Python/numpy code:

```
from numpy import fromfile

with open('File', 'rb') as fid:
    fromfile(fid, '<i1', 17) # do we need to specify LE here?
    twf = fromfile(fid, '<i2')
    points = twf.size
```

Comment: That'll do it; although `with open('File', 'rb') as fid:`   is more *en vogue* these days.

Comment: True! I wanted to keep it structurally similar to the Matlab code though, to better show which part matches which. And I'm not a big fan of nested structure, "Flat is better than nested". Anyway, edited it accordingly, thanks.